# How CocoaPods' install command works behind the scene to add files to my Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, applescript, cocoapods

I've started using CocoaPods. I like the way it adds files to my Xcode project but I'm curious about writing my own AppleScript to be able to add files to my Xcode project. How I can do that? Any reference would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xcode project file format is tough. There are 2 tools that CocoaPods can use to edit them. The [Xcodeproj](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) Ruby gem is the first. A lot of other projects such as [slather](https://github.com/venmo/slather) also depend on this gem to deal with the project files. If you have it installed CocoaPods can also use [xcproj](https://github.com/0xced/xcproj) to add things to your project. This can be installed with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with

```
brew install xcproj
```

It has to be recompiled each time you update Xcode. If you'd like to make a tool that manipulates your project I'd recommend these as your starting point.